# Why is my component rendered multiple times in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lifecycle, react-native-flatlist

I have a parent component (*uploadVimeo.js*), which calls a child component (*item.js*) when iterating through the list of videos.

**uploadVimeo.js**

```js
 export default class UploadVimeo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      videos: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const videos = await AsyncStorage.getItem('imagensSelecionadas');
    const videosToJson = JSON.parse(videos);
    const videosList = videosToJson.filter((video) => video.mime === 'video/mp4')

    videosList.forEach((video, index) => video.id = index.toString())
    this.setState({
      videos: videosList,
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      (this.state.videos.length > 0) &&
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.videos}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item key={item.id} name={item.filename} progress={0} />}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

**item.js**

```js
 class Item extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { props } = this;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, width: Dimensions.get("window").width, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
        <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
          <View style={styles.thumbnailContainer}>
            <Image source={{ uri: 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any' }} style={styles.thumbnail} resizeMode='cover' resizeMethod='auto' />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.name || 'Novo Video'}</Text>
            <Bar progress={props.progress} width={null} color='#00FF9D' borderRadius={0} borderWidth={0} unfilledColor='#CCCCCC' style={styles.infoBar} />
            <View style={styles.infoHeader}>
              <Text>57 segundos restantes</Text>
              <Text>{(props.progress * 100) || 0}%</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.actionsContainer}>
              <Icon.Button name='pause' backgroundColor='transparent' color='#CCC' onPress={() => startUpload()}>
                <Text>PAUSAR</Text>
              </Icon.Button>
              <Icon.Button name='times-circle' backgroundColor='transparent' color='#CCC' >
                <Text>CANCELAR</Text>
              </Icon.Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the content of my *this.state.videos*

```js
[
  {
    filename: "IMG_0011.MP4",
    hashId: "1eddbd20-aff8-11ea-b8fc-1b40f658f9c6",
    id: "0",
    isVideoYoutube: false,
    mime: "video/mp4",
    path: "file:///.../2C37F3A6-0A53-4224-9AFE-E36ECD916344.mp4",
    size: 212487,
  },
  {
    filename: "IMG_0011.MP4",
    hashId: "1eddbd20-aff8-11ea-b8fc-1b40f658f9c6",
    id: "1",
    isVideoYoutube: false,
    mime: "video/mp4",
    path: "file:///.../2C37F3A6-0A53-4224-9AFE-E36ECD916344.mp4",
    size: 212487,
  },
]
```

[Notice the number of times my component is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af5xs.png)

[What causes this problem in rendering my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0YLg.png)

EDIT: I added the entire code sheet to make it easier to understand

Comment: *Component renders multiple times in React Native* doesn't sound like a question :)

Comment: It is better now? @SirajAlam

Comment: If state didn't change causing the re render then it could be that your application is wrapped in React.StrictMode

Comment: Do both components have exactly same code? or is it just a mistake here?

Comment: There may be other state variables too that are causing the re-rending issue.

Comment: Very hard to deduce without the full code, but component mounts whenever state changes, and iemjs rendering multiple times seems ok. Does this.state.videos come by any api call? Also didn't get the second screenshot question.

Comment: @SirajAlam sorry, I hadn't noticed the error in the second code script

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal As edited in the question, the status of videos is mounted on ComponentDidMount () from AsyncStorage.

Comment: Replace forEach with for loop, forEach causes problem with async.

Comment: wrap the FlatList in a View and add a key. try this and let me know.